# Inverse of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

If $A, B, C$ are $n\times n$ matrices, with $B$ and $C$ nonsingular, and $b$ is a vector of size $n$, how would you determine $x = B^{-1} (2A+I)(C^{-1}+A)b$, without computing the inverses of matrices. How many operations will this computation require?

Comment: What makes you think this is possible? Is this a question from a textbook?

Comment: It is not from textbook.

Comment: What *is* it from?

Comment: It's just a homework problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

- solve $Cw=b$,
- $w:=w+Ab$,
- $w:=w+2Aw$
- solve $Bx=w$,

where "solve $Gy=c$" reads "solve the system $Gy=c$ by any suitable means", e.g., by using the LU factorisation.

The cost is determined essentially by the cost of the solve, which generally is $O(n^3)$.

Comment: what does w represent?

Comment: Well, since every matrix involved is $n\times n$ and $b$ is an $n$-vector, $w$ is an $n$-vector as well, that is, a solution of the system $Cw=b$.